# lldb in objective-c project that contain swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have one static lib objective-c target ,and I add swift in it;

In Bridging-Heade file  I import "Class.h" that is subclass of JSONModel ;

when use lldb po, it show "error: failed to import bridging header error: 'Class.h' file not found"

any can helps?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project -> Build settings -> search `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME`.
Check that it is `Class.h`. if not then check below.

1. You should import the value of `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME` in objective-c files (.h).

The the Bridging-Header file is in `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER`(search this key in Build setting), that is only reference for compiler. When you build project compiler generates `.h` file, the name is in `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME`.

Comment: my target can build sucess when objectvie-c call swift or swift call  objectvie-c ; but when lldb debug , it show  "failed to import bridging header error"

Comment: Were you able to solve this?